# Image In JavaScript Alert

Tags: javascript, image, alert

I know it's a unwise question but if it's possible -

Can we show a image in JavaScript alert box?

If it's possible, How can we do this?

Comment: Look for "modal dialog" in Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.** You cannot display an image inside JavaScript's native `alert()` box.

*Side note*: `alert()` displays what's given to it as input as pure text, meaning you cannot pass a string containing an `<img>` tag to it and expect it to display an image - it will instead display the string `"<img src...>"`.

Comment: Couldn't have been put in a better way! +1

Answer (score 1):

no it's not possible but why not make something that looks like it. for example a popup.

Answer (score 1):

JS alert box has no place to place image, but you can create your own alert style, as you wish, e.g. show a DIV at screen center with background dimmed (just like Facebook, and many other sites)

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible using the normal alert function, you may consider trying this using the [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to simulate the alertbox

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't display image with js alert box, but you can wit jquery. Maybe this plugin would be interesting for you:
[WowWindow plugin](http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/wowwindow/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with vanilla JavaScript, although you could use the `<div>` element, Bootstrap modals, or JavaScript libraries.

Bootstrap example: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but you can show the img in a modal.