# How do I display image in Alert/confirm box in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to display image in alert box or confirm box? I have been trying with below code but getting image url in the alert box. Please anybody help me to get solve or please give any other suggestions if it does not possible.

```
var image = document.getElementById("myImage").src="hackanm.gif";
alert("OnLoad image"+image );
```

Comment: That is not possible, those native dialogs take _text_ input only. Look into jQueryUI if you want more fancy dialogs.

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268197/image-in-javascript-alert

Comment: Yes thanku sir, Is there any plugins to achieve this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/FzsJR/1/ something like this??

Comment: @Ashish Yes u r rock bro.. Exactly I wanted this only.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alert boxes in JavaScript can only display pure text. You could use a JavaScript library like jQuery to display a modal instead?

This might be useful:
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

You can do it like this:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

  </script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Image:</p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Placeholder Image" />

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mark Winterbottom Is it possible to display images in Modal Dialog? Is there any possibilities to achieve this by using JQuery library?

Answer (score 8):

Snarky yet potentially useful answer:
<s>http://picascii.com/</s> (currently down)

https://www.ascii-art-generator.org/es.html
(don't forget to put a \n after each line!)

Comment: Brilliant idea.

Comment: Link is currently down.

Comment: @Sergio It was an ascii art generator that generated ascii art from a picture.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that libraries exist that also do image-to-ascii conversion. Including one in your project could allow you to change the image dynamically as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: You could use a ***modal*** to display a popup with the image you need.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992142/html-modal-popup) as an example to a modal.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery dialog to show image, try this code

```
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="divid">
         <img>
     </div>
    <body>
  </html>


<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("btn").click(function(){
      $("divid").dialog();
   });
  });  
 </script>
```

`

first you have to include jQuery UI at your Page.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3GLCx/)

Comment: Is it possible to display image element inside the div into dialog? I am not sure will it work or not? Can u please give fiddle for this example?

Comment: @Mallikarjun I have created fiddle for you, i think this will help you, http://jsfiddle.net/3GLCx/

Comment: Thanks brother.. One more thing tell me bro.. Can we get touch event on that image div NOT OK Button in the dialog?

Comment: Read jQuery UI documentation on jQuery site

Answer (score 1):

As other have mentioned you can't display an image in an alert.  The solution is to show it on the webpage.

If I have my webpage paused in the debugger and I already have an image loaded, I can display it.  There is no need to use jQuery; with this native 14 lines of Javascript it will work from code or the debugger command line:

```
function show(img){
 var _=document.getElementById('_'); 
 if(!_){_=document.createElement('canvas');document.body.appendChild(_);}
 _.id='_';
 _.style.top=0;
 _.style.left=0;
 _.width=img.width;
 _.height=img.height;
 _.style.zIndex=9999; 
 _.style.position='absolute';
 _.getContext('2d').drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

Usage:

```
show( myimage );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can emojis!

```
$('#test').on('click', () => {
    alert(' Build is too fast');
})
```

Comment: Useless but curious fact.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that might help. All it does is imitate the alert but put an image instead of text.

```
function alertImage(imgsrc) {
$('.d').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': '0',
    'left': '50%',
    '-webkit-transform': 'translate(-50%, 0)'
});
$('.d').animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 0)
$('.d').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    top: "10px"
}, 250)
$('.d').append('An embedded page on this page says')
$('.d').append('<br><img src="' + imgsrc + '">')
$('.b').css({
  'position':'absolute',
  '-webkit-transform': 'translate(-100%, -100%)',
  'top':'100%',
  'left':'100%',
  'display':'inline',
  'background-color':'#598cbd',
  'border-radius':'4px',
  'color':'white',
  'border':'none',
  'width':'66',
  'height':'33'
})
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div class="d"><button onclick="$('.d').html('')" class="b">OK</button></div>
```

```css
.d{
font-size: 17px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.b{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JS dialogs display only text, you could try using Emojis. For example:

```
alert('Hello friend! \u{1F642}');
```

You just need to use the unicode hex value for the emoji you want.
Here is a list of available emojis: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html