# how to get image as alert in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey am trying to get image as alert.

```
    function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

instead of text i want to get image

Comment: Can't be done, you probably want a custom modal or new window, not an alert ?

Comment: Alerts are evil things anyways. They stop JavaScript from being able to do anything while they're shown. They throw off timers, XHRs, websockets, and lock up the UI. Just don't use them. Use a modal like bootstrap's or jquery UI or something or build your own.

Comment: Check out: http://simplemodal.plasm.it/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display image in Alert/confirm box in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659173/how-do-i-display-image-in-alert-confirm-box-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with an alert box in native JavaScript, as various other posts on here have pointed out. What you want to do is use a library (or right your own) to simply show a message box. This is usually just a div, which you can easily add an image to. A lot of libraries do this, I think the one I use, bootstrap, has it to. Best of all, these boxes look far better than normal alerts!

(Look at the website posted in the comment above, it's what you want!)