# How to display an image in alert/message box in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to display an image in message box. Is it possible.

I am working in java script and jsp.

```
<script>
window.confirm(<img src="myimage.png" width="100" height="100" alt="plot" border=3 />);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in pure Javascript... but you can use an external library to achieve your goal.

Take a look here: [How do I display image in Alert/confirm box in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659173/how-do-i-display-image-in-alert-confirm-box-in-javascript)

The best suggestion uses a JQuery component: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Hope it help.