# JavaScript alert with image and link

Tags: javascript, html, browser, alert, chromium

I was navigating on this [**page**](http://www.google.com/hangouts/) and clicked "Available for your computer" image.

Then a native browser popup that is like an alert was opened:

> [image]

Please compare the one above with the following `alert()` that everybody knows:

> [image]

How did they create such an alert?

`alert` seems not to support images, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17268197/1420197).

Is this possible to open with JavaScript? I guess yes, but how?

Is this cross-browser? On Firefox, I am redirected to Chrome download page.

---

**NOTE:** I DO know that there are a lot of JavaScript libraries to show alerts, but I DO NOT want to use any of them. I want a clear answer to my question.

Comment: Do you mean something like a Modal Popup or a Popover ? Look @ Bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: @Webice No, the alert from my screen shot is a native browser thing, not HTML.

Comment: And how would you implement that cross Browser ?

Comment: @Webice I was just asking. If it's Chrome/Chromium specific, that's good to know also.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has some specialized windows/popups available for it's own use .. things you can't do via regular JavaScript.

Other things you can't do via regular JavaScript are the

- Enable Webcam prompt window
- Download file window.

If you are trying to do something similar in pure JavaScript, this is a great little replacement:

http://www.codersgrid.com/2013/07/05/alertify-js-replacement-of-your-browser-alert-dialog/

Comment: Well, but how they start this popup? Because that's JavaScript I guess.

Comment: @Webice It's a webpage. Who opens that popup when I trigger the click event?

Comment: Here is how you find out out they started it:  Go to Chrome. Turn on the development tools.  Go to the profile tab and start profiling.  After the popup comes up, dismiss it then turn off profiling.  Look through all the code that executed.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Chrome can unminimize the code, and that process is the same process *I'd* have to follow to answer the 'How' question.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher *Chrome has some specialized windows/popups available for it's own use .. things you can't do via regular JavaScript.* - Without a reference this doesn't help too much...

Comment: @IonicăBizău These are things, for Chrome, by Chrome developers.  The basic upshot is -- they aren't for general use.  You'll either have to read code or go find some Chrome development resources.  Either way, you won't be able to use them from regular user-level JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a "chrome specific" popup. The application you want to install by clicking on this button is a Google App, which install is handled by Chrome. I think.
Except Bootstrap-like modals, I have never seen such thing in Javascript before.

Check this if you want to implement such popups on your website:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

instead of using alert . you can use any external plugin confirm box.Then you can customize your dialog box